# How can I replace the whole table's content with another table's content

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, orm, peewee

I need to replace the whole content of one table with another table's content. Both tables have the same fields.

I don't see any way to execute `ALTER TABLE` statement via [Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/), so I decided to use the combination of `DROP TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... FROM` statements like this:

```
TableInWhichIWantToReplaceAllData.drop_table()
db.create_table(TableInWhichIWantToReplaceAllData)
TableWithNewData.insert_from(
    # ???,
    # ???
).execute()
```

But the problem is how can I specify **all** fields to be `SELECT`ed and `INSERT`ed? I don't want to manually specify all of them like in example:

```
source = (User
          .select(User.username, fn.COUNT(Tweet.id))
          .join(Tweet, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
          .group_by(User.username))
UserTweetDenorm.insert_from(
    [UserTweetDenorm.username, UserTweetDenorm.num_tweets],
    source).execute()
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peewee supports table changes via the [migrations extension](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations). Specifically it sounds like you want to [rename a table](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#SchemaMigrator.rename_table).

Alternatively, you can use the INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM as you have. To get all the fields on a model, you can use `ModelClass._meta.sorted_fields` (2.7.0 and newer) or `ModelClass._meta.get_fields()` (2.6.4 and older).

```
   select = TableWithData.select()
   insert = NewTable.insert_from(NewTable._meta.get_fields(), select)
```

I believe that should do the trick, but honestly...just use the migrator.